# Force display: table element to not overstep parent element width

Tags: css

How can I prevent the `display: table` element overstepping its parent element width?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpfLxkrh/1/) of the below:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <span class="cell">
               <select>
                   <option>long long long long long desc</option>
                </select>
            </span>
    <span class="cell">A</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In effect, the `.table` element is wider than `.container`.

How can I prevent that and keep max-width of `.table` 100% of parent element? (`max-width` is not working).

I'm looking for pure CSS solution.

Comment: In fact your question can be resumed like : "How to force `display: table` to behave like `display: block`"

Comment: @Adrift I was about to post that solution. that would be my answer as well ;)

Comment: @Brewal In CSS specs they say that `display: table` will change element display way like a `<table>` ... I can fit table width to 100%. I need to use `display: table-cell` elements inside so for me this is not `display: block` elements behavior

Comment: I mean, a table will always overflow from its parent if its own content is too large. Try to set your `select` max-width instead

Comment: @Adrift I'm using this element inside bootstrap structure so parent element always has defined width in precents, than unfortunately this solution will fail

Comment: @Brewal not always, you can change `table-layout` CSS property, unfortunately it's not working on `display: table` elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not your `display: table` div... it is your `select`.

If you want to keep that width, make it behave!

```
select {
    width: 100%;
}
```

### Example

The select size will now be controlled by its cell size. I have changed the cell sizes to 50% to illustrate this.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f00;
}
select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <span class="cell">
            <select>
                <option>long long long long long desc</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    <span class="cell">A</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Very simple:

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/zpfLxkrh/3/

you need two things:

```
.table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
select {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: **table-layout: fixed;** is what I was looking for, thanks!